# In Scrapy, how to proceed to parse method after getting HTTP403

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape a website which returns HTTP403 if JavaScript is not enabled.

The methodology that I'm trying to implement is,
**in the parse method, Selenium driver gets the url from `response.requets.url` and fetch the page**

But the issue I'm facing is selenium is automatically closing the request after getting HTTP403 and not entering into the parse method.

Here is my code:

```py
class SampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "sample_spider"
    start_urls = ["https://website_that_returning_403.com"]

    def parse(self, response):
        bot = webdriver.Chrome()
        bot.get(response.request.url)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle status other than those in the `200-300` range you use the `handle_httpstatus_list` spider attribute as below

```py
class SampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "sample_spider"
    handle_httpstatus_list = [403]
    start_urls = ["https://website_that_returning_403.com"]

    def parse(self, response):
        bot = webdriver.Chrome()
        bot.get(response.request.url)
```

Read more about it from the [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#module-scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror)